# Add sheet with column names to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, cmd

How can I add a sheet to an existing Excel spreadsheet?

This code is saved to a `.cmd` file and currently overwrites the `report.xls` file if it exists with a new file.

```
IF EXIST %1\Report.xls DEL %1\Report.xls
COPY %1\ReportTemplate.xls %1\Report.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is not possible in cmd, if you have powershell available you could write a ps script and start it from your batch file (or just do everything in powershell :))

If you want to try it there is a COM Object for working in excel Files, its name is "excel.application".

Here is how you would create such an object in powershell:

```
$xls = new-object -comobject excel.application
```

you can then open your xls File and edit it (for further instructions just google).

Regards